# Recursive function to ensure the return length is 5

Tags: javascript

I'm fetching some data from an xml source, but I need to check that the length of the array (return value) is 5, sometimes the response serves data with less than 5 elements (it's random).

If the return value (`colorArray`) is 5, the promise resolves with the correct array. Otherwise, if the function re-runs the promise resolves with **undefined**.

Appreciate any help in understanding why I'm getting undefined when `colorArray.length` is less than 5, or if anyone has any better suggestions about how I should run the code.

Thanks.

```
    const runAxios = async () => {
      console.log("function");
      const res = await axios.get("/api/palettes/random");

      let parser = new DOMParser();
      let xml = parser.parseFromString(res.data, "application/xml");

      let colors = xml.getElementsByTagName("hex");
      const colorArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        let colorList = colors[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        colorArray.push(colorList);
      }
      if (colorArray.length === 5) return colorArray;
      else runAxios();
    };

    const result = runAxios();

    result.then(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
```

Comment: Where do you return anything?

Comment: Add flag above run axios and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem is that you never returned `runAxios`:

```js
    const runAxios = async () => {
      console.log("function");
      const res = await axios.get("/api/palettes/random");

      let parser = new DOMParser();
      let xml = parser.parseFromString(res.data, "application/xml");

      let colors = xml.getElementsByTagName("hex");
      const colorArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        let colorList = colors[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        colorArray.push(colorList);
      }
      if (colorArray.length === 5) return colorArray;
      else return runAxios(); // <----------------------------------This
    };

    const result = runAxios();

    result.then(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
```

### Also, depending on your requirements, I would suggest a do-while loop:

```js
const runAxios = async () => {
      do {
          console.log("function");
          const res = await axios.get("/api/palettes/random");

          let parser = new DOMParser();
          let xml = parser.parseFromString(res.data, "application/xml");

          let colors = xml.getElementsByTagName("hex");
          const colorArray = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            let colorList = colors[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
            colorArray.push(colorList);
          }
      } while(colorArray.length != 5);
      return colorArray;
    };

    const result = runAxios();

    result.then(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
```